# Change local IP address programmatically?

Tags: networking, ip, .net-framework

I have a local network in my home with my ADSL(Router) modem.
We can change our IP with the following setting in Windows
[image: IPV4]
Is it possible do it programmatically, e.g. using C#.Net?

Comment: unfortunately, this is not a security question but a Windows config question - migrating

Comment: Depending on your use case and platform, you may be better off looking for methods to script it with PowerShell or using `NETSH`.

Comment: Yes it can be done programatically, but it would be much easier to use something like a batch script vs. C#.

Comment: Just a suggestion, such as DrZoo said, it would be better to use something like a batch script.  I would just use Netsh, browse through the help options, and figure out all the commands you need to run.  When you create a batch script that works, you could always use C# to run the script.  Not sure how you would change those settings in C#, but I don't think it will be easy (compared to running a script).

Comment: Take the above comments and combine them, have C# generate a script and then run it.

Comment: The setIP() function in the answer to this question looks right up your alley - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code